# Issues with Lionbars (a CSS scrollbar widget)

Tags: css, widget, scrollbar

I really like the [lionbars widget](https://github.com/Charuru/lionbars), but there are a few things that aren't working out. I've dug into all these issues locally, so I thought I would ask if there's known ways to work this, before I start re-arranging the code.

- horizontal scrolling is not working (vertical is)
- scrollpane (and corresponding scrollbars) is not resized on window resize
- there's a weird discoloration on the right side of the vertical bar if the window is zoomed out too high
- can I control scrollbar width ; the default vertical scrollbar is too narrow

Comment: Hi Frye, could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: Well I tried to put a basic code example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3XPNk/3/ . But lionbars doesn't even seem to be loaded. It put that in the Managed Resources section.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your issues in order:

1. **Horizontal scroll:** Your code *is* loaded on JSFiddle, but you've set LionBars on the wrong div. Just set the LionBar function on `#parent` instead of `#child` and horizontal scroll should work: http://jsfiddle.net/3XPNk/8/

   *However*, I've found that the horizontal scroll will *not* work in Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) on my Mac due to an issue with how the browsers treat horizontal scrollbars and how the LionBars script itself detects a horizontal scrollbar. You may want to contact the developer about this.
2. **Scrollpane not resizing:** Not sure what you mean. Please elaborate? You've defined `#parent` and `#child` as fixed pixel sizes, so they will obviously not resize. Try percentages if you want it to resize fluidly.
3. **"Weird discoloration":** This is because the script actually just offsets the real scrollbars beyond the viewable area of the scrolling div by a pixel amount. Once you zoom out, this breaks because the scrollbar width changes proportionally with zoom and the offset amount becomes too small to squeeze out all of the scrollbars. That weird discoloration you see is a bit of the scrollbar squeezing back into view. Again, you probably want to tell the developer about this.
4. **Changing scrollbar width:** Yup! Just edit the values for `.vertical` and `.horizontal` in `lionbars.css`.

Fixing issues 1 & 3 above will require some fiddling around with the script. This is not exactly the same (there is no nifty fade and you will have to style it significantly on your own), but you may want to consider using this plugin instead, as it seems to be more developed and compatible overall: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. I'll have to come back to lionbars at some point. I went with a hand-rolled solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/RzHJP/